# process substitution to mimic file

Tags: bash, shell, process-substitution

I can't recall how to accomplish this, I am trying to support users to be able to include plaintext in their commands for temp usage:

Here it reads from a file, file.json:

```
lp_solve --method='simplex' --problem='<file.json>'
```

But I would like users to be able to write json inline using process substitution:

```bash
lp_solve --method='exhaustive' --problem=<(echo '
   {"foo":"bar","this":"is json"}
')
```

will that do the trick cross-platform? Do I need to put quotes around the '<()'?

Comment: What do you mean by *cross-platform*? You mean regardless of the system as long as the shell is bash? or *that works will all shells that support ksh-style process-substitution*? Or *regardless of the application that is passed the result of that process substitution*?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the shell is bash, zsh or a recent version of ksh93¹ and the feature has not be disabled at build time²,

```
lp_solve --method='simplex' --problem=<(echo 'something')
```

Will call `lp_solve` with its last argument being `--problem=/path/to/some/file`, where `/path/to/some/file` identifies the reading end of a pipe. Either `/dev/fd/n` as is the original ksh implementation or a named pipe or `/proc/self/fd/n`.

Other shells either don't support process substitution or support it with a different syntax (`<{cmd}` in rc-like shells, `(cmd | psub)` in `fish`) and/or `<(cmd)` is used for something else (like process redirection in `yash` or `<` redirection followed by command substitution in `fish`)

The fact that the file is a pipe has several implications which means it cannot always be used as a one-to-one replacement to a regular file:

- the application (here `lp_solve`) cannot seek inside the file
- if the application opens it a second time after having read it once, it will appear as empty.
- trying to write to the file will either fail or not work as expected

zsh and fish have forms of process substitution that use temporary regular files:

- `... --problem==(echo '...')` (zsh)
- `... --problem=(echo '...' | psub -f)` (fish)

Except the the `"$(echo ... | psub)"` of recent versions of `fish`, process substitution is not performed inside quotes, so you do **not** want to use quotes around those.

Remember that `echo` can't be used portably even in bash for arbitrary text and specifically not for text that contains `\` characters (common in json). You may want to use `printf` instead.

Here in addition of having a `--problem` that takes a file as argument, you could have one that takes a json string. Like `--problem-file=file.json` and `--problem='{"some": "json"}'`. Or since a json string can't start with `@`, do like `curl` does for some of its options and, have `--problem='{"some": "json"}'` and `--problem=@file.json`.

---

<sup>¹ process substitution comes from ksh in the mid 80s but was only available on systems that had `/dev/fd/n` support and the expansion could not be part of an argument, `--problem <(cmd)` would have worked, not `--problem=<(cmd)` (still the case until some relatively recent version of ksh93)</sup>

<sup>² in bash, process substitution is disabled if the `configure` script is called with `--disable-process-substitution` or `--enable-minimal-config`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

### Note

I've noticed that `lp_solve` is a *math* program so the code below will not be able to work as you want. This because the programs expects a pathname.

---

When you use process substitution you should read what you pass to the script from the stdin (it's like a pipe I assume).

Now, if `lp_solve` were a custom programming/shell script (e.g. bash) then you should use the following content to read the stdin:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo Data:
cat
```

And to pass the `stdin` you should use:

```
lp_solve --method='simplex' --problem=< <(echo Fuzz)
#Output:
Data:
Fuzz
```

However, as you can see above the `< <(echo Fuzz)` is taken as `stdin` and not as parameter so you will not be able to read from any `$N` variables.

If you want to pass as a parameter to your script you should use:

```bash
lp_solve --method='simplex' --problem='
{"foo":"bar","this":"is json"}
{"foo":"buzz","this":"is json"}
{"foo":"foo","this":"is json"}
etc...
'
```

When you type `lp_solve --method='simplex' --problem='` you should press enter to be able to *complete* your string.
Btw, be careful when using `--problem='` because if you type `'` the string will be completed. For example:

```bash
lp_solve --method='simplex' --problem='
this is a text
this is a'text
#Output:
this is a text
this is atext
```

As you can see the `'` was removed. I assume that in others shells the behavior might be different or the script could fail.

Comment: "you should read what you pass to the script from the stdin (it's like a pipe I assume)" – Not necessarily. `echo <(:)` prints something like `/dev/fd/63`. It *is* a pathname. `<(…)` can be used where a program expects a pathname, the very point of it is to turn a pipe into a pathname. The file is not seekable though. In Zsh you can use `=(…)` to get a pathname of a seekable (temporary) file. Anyway, `cp <(echo foo) test1` has nothing to do with the stdin of `cp` and yet it works; there is nothing to fix by making `cp` read from its stdin. The OP's `lp_solve` like `cp` expects a pathname.

Comment: The `--problem=` option expects a filename not a stdin, thus the `< <(...)` wouldn't work.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks for the clarification!  I would like to know what is the difference between `command <()` and `command < <()`. Because with `< <(echo Fuzz)` I get fuzz from the stdin while with `< (echo fuzz) ` I get the path.

Comment: @annahri the OP wants to pass a *string/stdin*. *"But I would like users to be able to write json inline using process substitution"*

Comment: @EdgarMagallon The difference? The shell replaces `<(…)` with a pathname in each case. `cmmnd <(…)` works like `cmmnd pathname`. `cmmnd opt=<(…)` works like `cmmnd opt=pathname`. `cmmnd < <(…)` works like `cmmnd < pathname`. The rest of the magic is that the `pathname` leads to a pipe from which the output of `…` can be read.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks! The last sentence was successful to understand why the process substitution works like a pipe.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon "the OP wants to pass a string" – Yes, but `lp_solve --problem=` apparently *takes a pathname*. `<(…)` is a way to make the output of an arbitrary command (e.g. `echo`) available from a file (pipe) the program can open.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I misunderstood the question! I see. My first solution will not be able to write the json inline while the second solution will work *successfully*. Or am I wrong with the second solution?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon "The second solution" is the one with `--problem='…'` where `…` is some multi-line text, right? Well, if `--problem=` expects a pathname to a file (and it seems so) then giving the content of the file instead is wrong. The program will treat the string you provided as a pathname, it will try to open it, this will fail. `--problem=<(echo …)` in question works because the shell substitutes `<(…)` with some valid pathame. It's not that something doesn't work. No solution is needed. Read the explicit questions: "cross-platform? Do I need to put quotes?". These are the questions.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I also read about `lp_solve` and it seems is a *math* program. My mistake was to think that it could be a (custom) shell script. So as you said both solution I provided don't really resolve the problem. I have to clarify that in my answer. Thanks for your comments!